# What is the lifecycle of a fileprivate variable in Swift?

Tags: swift, memory-management

`fileprivate` variables can be accessed from the their entire files. At what point memory is allocated and deallocated for this variable?

Comment: Can you give an example? variable lifecycle depends on scope